# Auto generate ID in java

Tags: java, oracle, auto-generate

I am developing a web application using *JSP* + *Servlets* and *Oracle10* as *back-end*.

I have a table for storing information related to Customers:

```
|ID        |Name            |City          |
|N0001     |ABC             |NASIK         |
|N0002     |PQR             |NASIK         |
|N....     |...             |NASIK         |
|N9999     |XYZ             |NASIK         |
|N10000    |LMN             |NASIK         |
|N10001    |MNO             |NASIK         |
```

In above table `ID` is a primary key, which is auto-generated depending upon the `City` (first Character of `City` + Number(Number must be minimum 4 character long, so for first ID, three leading zeroes will be added to number))

`For Generating ID:` 
I am using following query for getting Largest ID from table, and then some java code Auto Generate Next `ID`.

```
query = "select ID from CUST where CITY='NASIK' order by ID desc";
```

Then getting the first `ID` from `ResultSet` which is as expected till the ID reach to the `N9999`, but when `ID` is `N10000` or above then query is giving me `N9999` as Largest `ID`.

Output after `N9999`:

```
ID
----------
N9999
N10001
N10000
N0002
N0001
```

Output Expecting

```
ID
----------
N10001
N10000
N9999
N0002
N0001
```

So my question is that is there anything wrong in above query? Or is there any better way to Auto Generate ID which contains String.

**Edit1**
My requirement is to auto generate `ID` which will contain character at starting position.

Comment: select ID from CUST where CITY='NASIK' order by substr(ID,2) desc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this query

```
select ID from CUST where CITY='NASIK' order by to_number(substr(ID,2)) desc;
```

Answer (score 2):

Since ID is a String not a number, it is sorted differently. it would sort as you wish if you had done sth like:

```
0001N
0002N
...
```

or stored only numbers, not Strings

Comment: Thanks for the answer but My requirement is to auto generate ID which will contain character at starting position.

Comment: I see, then you'll have to use substr and be sure (might not scale well) how many characters to skip

Answer (score 1):

With the INSERT, without inserting the prinary key ID, you can get the "generated keys."

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO Customers(Name, City) VALUES (?, ?)";
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql,
     PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
stmt.setString(1, ...);
stmt.setString(2, ...);
int affectedRows = stmt.executeUpdate();

// Get the ID:
String pk = "";
ResultSet keys = stmt.getGeneratedKeys();
if (keys.next()) {
    pk = keys.getString(1);
}
```

It is so ugly, loop x loop, as one could have inserted more than one row, and the generated keys per row could be more than one.

*As you can see, this is prove against concurrent parallel INSERTS.*

About the sorting problem: you might go for a purely numerical ID, maybe a composed primary key CHAR(1), INT.

Answer (score 1):

quick fix would be to increase the number of leading '0' after the character. But then the problem will occur later (e.g. 99999 and 100000).

Hence i would suggest to interpret the ID as a number from the second character on and do the order comparison upon that number value.

Comment: just recognized that the second solution was already mentioned by @chetan